# Does protobuf java support initialization from text?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

In c++, we could use google::protobuf::TextFormat::Parse(input, proto) to initialize the proto with the inputStream input, if input satisfies some format.

Does protobuf java support this feature? if yes, what is the file format? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using the same text file format.

Just use `TextFormat.merge`, passing in either the text itself as a `CharSequence` or a `Readable` (e.g. `Reader`) and a builder to merge the values into.

See the [Javadoc for `TextFormat`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/TextFormat) for more information, and be aware that it's not available in the "lite" runtime.